# How can i find which pattern matches subject?

Tags: php, regex

Suppose I have an array of patterns

```
array(
       '/foo\d+/',
       '/bar\d+/',
       '/baz\d+/'
      )
```

And I know that only one pattern will match the subject eg `foo12`

how would I go about establishing which pattern matches?

Do I have to  loop through the array with `preg_match`?

or is there a fancier solution using `preg_replace_callback` or something?

Comment: The purpose of multiple match patterns in one call is to not care which one matched. If you don't want to use multiple calls, then a *workaround* could be named capture groups.

Comment: https://eval.in/216347 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you do this

```
preg_match('/(foo|bar|baz)\d+/', $input, $match);
```

Then `$match[1]` will have your named bit `foo` or `bar` or `baz`, then say like this

```
switch( $match[1] ){
    case 'foo':

    break;
    case 'bar':

    break;
    case 'baz':

    break;

}
```

Ect..